# deletions and so

Tags: feature-request, deletion

Recently it is driving me a bit mad:

There  was a question, something about Datalog and logic, I post a comment, think about it for an evening, the next day I have thought about it but I cannot find the question anywhere, my comment is not even in my activity record.

Am I imagining that I did all this? Was the question removed/ deleted in the mean time? I cannot find any trace of the question or my activity.

Another example

I answered a question, the OP answered with a comment (for some clarification) , I mull a bit on the comment, wanted to change my answer because of it... oops the comment is gone (probably deleted by the op)

Can we not keep deleted comments, posts en at least for a couple of days? So that even if the OP decided the comment or question is no use to them, sometimes it is a good comment anyway.

Comment: "Am I imagining that i did all this? was the question removed/ deleted in the mean time?" Both possible. Unless you are prone to imagining things, the second is much more likely.

Comment: The [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/679368/how-to-prove-a-theory-based-on-using-resolution-to-find-all-dyadic-definite-clau) was deleted by the owner. You might still be able to see it in Google's cache.

Comment: Here is [Google's cached version](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:jlfh-eeXv74J:math.stackexchange.com/questions/679368/how-to-prove-a-theory-based-on-using-resolution-to-find-all-dyadic-definite-clau)